# problem in reading products CSV file with pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have products CSV file and I am trying to read this file with pandas python but i get this error

my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\work\\amazon\\move_in_links\\final.csv')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Compu City\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Compu City\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Compu City\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Compu City\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 875, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7549, saw 8
```

[this is the link of file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yr9RrT8YZuL6G7WNxpwfkHZgYutKW38n/view?usp=sharing)

---

another thing when I deleted most of the rows and remain just 4 rows the file read.

Comment: Just pass `error_bad_lines=False` argument when you read dataframe. This error occurs when  your csv file have some offending line. It will ignore that lines

Comment: it solved but now i got data as text sperated with ;

Comment: but in excel file each value in separated cell

Comment: @EslamTantawy excel has its own parsers, I suspect it handles errors for you on read ins.

Comment: Yes, Your file use delimiter as `;` so you should pass external argument `sep=';`. Try using `df = pd.read_csv('YOUR_CSV_PATH', sep=';')`. this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default pandas assumes your csv is separated by commas `','`, you should pass the proper separator to the read_csv call.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\work\\amazon\\move_in_links\\final.csv', sep=';')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

File appears to be separated by `;`. Try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\work\\amazon\\move_in_links\\final.csv',sep=";")
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps, this approach suggested by Ransaka works

> Blockquote

use delimiter as; so you should pass external argument sep=';. Try using df = pd.read_csv('YOUR_CSV_PATH', sep=';')

> Blockquote

And you can just use the file name as it is instead of a path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).